# Decrease the Image size at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have List Box with a DataTemplate, in the DataTemplate i have a Image. Below is my code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
            <Border  
                    Background="#FFFFFF"
                    Margin="0,2,0,0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
           <Grid  Width="Auto"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center">
         <Image   Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}"
                  Stretch="UniformToFill"
                  Source="{Binding ImageName}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Margin="1,1,1,1"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

My images are Quite big say 1000x1000 but i want to reduce the image size at run time, so that it will look good in the list box item.

How can i acheive this ?

I have tried to add the below code in `ImageStyle of Image`

```
<Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="210"/>
<Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="210"/>
```

but it will reduce the View size and not image size, so my images are cutting.

Note: Please note that i am working on Windows Phone 8 application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you mean by

> it will reduce the View size and not image size

but it you don't want your image clipped you should set [`Stretch="Uniform"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Uniform: The content is resized to fit in the destination dimensions while it preserves its native aspect ratio.

and you set it to `Stretch="UniformToFill"`

> UniformToFill: The content is resized to fill the destination dimensions while it preserves its native aspect ratio. **If the aspect ratio of the destination rectangle differs from the source, the source content is clipped to fit in the destination dimensions**.

Comment: After setting it Stretch="Uniform" its working fine, but i have one more question, There are 4 different size of devices ,WVGA 512,WVGA,WXVGA,720p , i have set the MaxHeight and MaxWidth to 210 , but how will the images look good or with proper size  in all devices ?

Comment: What i meant was MaxWidth and MaxHeight 210 as i have tested on emulator for WVGA 512 the images looks good, but what is the gaurentee that the images will look good on all other device with size 210? if not how to fix this?

Comment: You've tagged you question WPF, Silverlight and Windows Phone. If this is WPF then you can control it with [`RenderOptions.EdgeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.edgemode(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.bitmapscalingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can set for example `<Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" ... />` but, as far as I know, it does not exist in versions for Silverlight and Windows Phone

Comment: ok, i will accept the answer, i have one more query realated to list box caan you please help me ?

Comment: If you require some more clarification regarding this question I can try. If not it's better to ask another question

Comment: No not about this question, i have a query related to list box and multiple data template with onclick selection, i am not able to explain it properly if i post a question, thats why i am requesting you to please help me on that

Comment: Ask another question then. If not me then someone else will be able to help you. It will be easier for you to explain the problem and for someone to give you proper answer

Comment: ok, here the question , please help me to fix this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578128/list-box-with-multiple-data-template-style-for-selected-item